# Making DOM IE Friendly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

How can I make this script IE friendly? The only parts that aren't IE friendly are the variables `scrolledtonum` and `heightofbody`...

```
function getheight() {

            var myWidth = 0,
        myHeight = 0;
         if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
                //Non-IE
                myWidth = window.innerWidth;
                myHeight = window.innerHeight;
            } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
                //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
                myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            } else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
                //IE 4 compatible
                myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
            }
            var scrolledtonum = window.pageYOffset + myHeight + 2;
            var heightofbody = document.body.offsetHeight;
            if (scrolledtonum >= heightofbody) {
                document.body.scrollTop = 0;
            }
        }

        window.onscroll = getheight; 

        function func() {
            window.document.body.scrollTop++;
        }

        window.document.onmouseover = function () {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };

        window.document.onmouseout = function () {
            interval = setInterval(func, 20);
        };

        var interval = setInterval(func, 20);
```

Comment: @Mike Samuel Not in quirks mode.

Comment: do you really have IE4 users? if not, get rid of the IE4 support code.

Comment: You never know... Probably not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mozilla MDN documentation for scrollY contains sample code for dealing with compatibility issues with pageYOffset: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.scrollY.

It says the following:

For cross-browser compatibility, use `window.pageYOffset` instead of `window.scrollY`, except use

```
(((t = document.documentElement) || (t = document.body.parentNode)) && typeof t.ScrollTop == 'number' ? t : document.body).ScrollTop
```

when `window.pageYOffset` (and `window.scrollY`) is undefined.

Comment: I added the code: (Here it is) Is there anything I am doing wrong here? http://pastebin.com/nqaUQTW6

Comment: You might want to change ScrollTop to scrollTop - it should be case sensitive.

Comment: I wondered about that too.  This is verbatim copied from the MDN page and I wondered if some very old browsers had it as `ScrollTop`?