# IE Compliant Code Not Working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making DOM IE Friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738493/making-dom-ie-friendly)

What I am doing wrong here? (it is supposed to be IE compliant, but it doesn't work at all)

```
function getheight() {

            var myWidth = 0,
        myHeight = 0;
         if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
                //Non-IE
                myWidth = window.innerWidth;
                myHeight = window.innerHeight;
            } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
                //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
                myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            }
            var scrolledtonum = (((t = document.documentElement) || (t = document.body.parentNode)) && typeof t.ScrollTop == 'number' ? t : document.body).ScrollTop + myHeight + 2;
            alert(scrolledtonum);
            var heightofbody = document.body.offsetHeight;
            if (scrolledtonum >= heightofbody) {
                document.body.scrollTop = 0;
            }
        }

        window.onscroll = getheight; 

        function func() {
            window.document.body.scrollTop++;
        }

        window.document.onmouseover = function () {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };

        window.document.onmouseout = function () {
            interval = setInterval(func, 20);
        };

        var interval = setInterval(func, 20);
```

What can I do to make it IE compliant once I have fixed it?

Comment: FYI, "IE4 market share dropped under 1% by 2004". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_4

Comment: That really isn't very constructive.

Comment: Should I do that now? Or will this question suffice?

Comment: I hope you're not rewriting jQuery here. [innerHeight](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/) is an example of something like this, and there are other methods that do variations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the line starting with  `var scrolledtonum = (`

```
.ScrollTop + myHeight + 2;
```

(the S in ScrollTop has to be lowercase)

Furthermore: be sure that getheight() will not be called before the document's onload-event has fired, otherwise `document.body.offsetHeight` may not return correct values.

Comment: I applied those changes, and `(((t = document.documentElement) || (t = document.body.parentNode)) && typeof t.scrollTop == 'number' ? t : document.body).ScrollTop` is returned as 0.